# Wordpress Login Form Validation

Tags: wordpress, validation, authentication

I have create custom wordpress login with validation but there is a problem once submit the email and the password no validation shows even with success or error i'm trying to build custom user auth i have created register and reset password the rest which is login and profile page under developing so i have created all needed redirection to allow my custom pages to take place of the wordpress default pages so i need to know what's wrong with my code and how to redirect after login to custom page here is my code

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    $error = '';
    $success = '';

            // check if we're in login form
    if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && 'login' == $_POST['action'] ) 
    {
        $email = trim($_POST['log']);
        $password = trim($_POST['pwd']);

        if( empty( $email ) || empty( $password ) ) {
            $error = 'Enter a username or e-mail address..';
        } else if( ! password_exists( $password ) ) {
            $error = 'password is incorrect.';
        } else if( ! is_email( $email )) {
            $error = 'Invalid username or e-mail address.';
        } else if( ! email_exists( $email ) ) {
            $error = 'There is no user registered with that email address.';
        } else {
            if( email_exists( $email ) ) {
                $success = 'successfully loged in.';

        } else {
            $error = 'Oops something went wrong while loging in to your account.';
        }

        }

        if( ! empty( $error ) )
            echo 'error text'; 

        if( ! empty( $success ) )
            echo 'error text'; 
    }
<!-- Show logged out message if user just logged out -->
<?php if ( $attributes['logged_out'] ) : ?>
<p class="login-info">
    <?php _e( 'You have signed out. Would you like to sign in again?', 'personalize-login' ); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $attributes['registered'] ) : ?>
<p class="login-info">
    <?php
            printf(
                __( 'You have successfully registered to <strong>%s</strong>. We have emailed your password to the email address you entered.', 'personalize-login' ),
                get_bloginfo( 'name' )
            );
        ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $attributes['lost_password_sent'] ) : ?>
<p class="login-info">
    <?php _e( 'Check your email for a link to reset your password.', 'personalize-login' ); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $attributes['password_updated'] ) : ?>
<p class="login-info">
    <?php _e( 'Your password has been changed. You can sign in now.', 'personalize-login' ); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>


<!-- START Login Form -->
<form id="form-login" class="p-t-15" action="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>">
    <!-- START Form Control-->
    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label>Login</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php $user_login = isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ? $_POST['user_login'] : ''; ?>
            <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Form Control-->
    <!-- START Form Control-->
    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label>Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php $user_pass = isset( $_POST['user_pass'] ) ? $_POST['user_pass'] : ''; ?>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="user_pass" placeholder="Credentials" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- START Form Control-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding sm-p-l-10">
            <div class="checkbox ">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox1">
                <label for="checkbox1">Keep Me Signed in</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
            <a href="#" class="text-info small">Help? Contact Support</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Form Control-->
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-cons m-t-10" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
<!--END Login Form-->
```

Comment: sending login data with `GET` ? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Form elements are passed by `name`, not by `id`, i.e. in your case you will need to get `$_GET['log']` for the user name, not `$_GET['user_login']`.

**However:** There are many problems with this code. You shouldn't pass private info via GET, shouldn't tell the user whether a login error involves the user name or the password, etc. If you rewrite this code with best practices in mind, it will be easier to find problems with the functional flow.

Comment: i have modified the code with ur further instruction, most tutorials over the internet provide a code for login form but when it comes to form validation they didn't provide and if they are as tuts tutorials the validation didn't show, thats why i'm trying to figure out a way to achieve that

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to write a WordPress plugin for login (there are many security considerations) without first understanding how forms, URLs, etc. work.

In any case, in your new edits you changed `$_GET['action']` to `$_POST['action']` but you don't have a form element with the name 'action'. If it's passed by URL, then this variable is GET (but the form elements are POST). Naturally the form method needs to be POST as well.

If you need a tutorial, try this: https://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/

Comment: i found a good code and acually uses right now from tuts https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-1-replace-the-login-page--cms-23627 everything setup  for errors message and unfortunately it's not visible if there is an error the url bar get error name but to echo those errors over the page nothing shoes